# "Protected" access in Python - how?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, protected

I would like to set up a class hierarchy in Python 3.2 with 'protected' access: Members of the base class would be in scope only for derived classes, but not 'public'.

A double underscore makes a member 'private', a single underscore indicates a warning but the member remains 'public'. What (if any...) is the correct syntax for designating a 'protected' member.

Comment: No can do. Use the `_single_underscore` convention and be happy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Member access allowance in Python works by "negotiation" and "treaties", not by force.

In other words, the user of your class is supposed to leave their hands off things which are not their business, but you cannot enforce that other than my using `_xxx` identifiers making absolutely clear that their access is (normally) not suitable.

Comment: So it's not possible. OK. But I do have a problem with 'treaties' not 'force' which I have voiced numerous times: the idea behind access specifiers is not really to prevent other people from doing something mean. It's about clear, structured organization of your code. I want my language to HELP ME DO THAT, not leave openings for all kinds of crazy hacks, which are all to common in Python code I often see. (Indicating that I probably shouldn't be using Python...)

Answer (score 3):

Double underscores don't make a member 'private' in the C++ or Java sense - Python quite explicitly eschews that kind of language-enforced access rules. A *single* underscore, by convention, marks an attribute or a method as an "implementation detail" - that is, things outside can still get to it, but this isn't a supported part of the class' interface and, therefore, the guarantees that the class might make about invariants or back/forwards compatibility no longer apply. This solves the same conceptual problem as 'private' (separation of interface and implementation) in a different way.

Double underscores invoke name mangling which still isn't 'private' - it is just a slightly stronger formulation of the above, whereby:
  - This function is an implementation detail of this class, *but*
  - Subclasses might reasonably expect to have a method of the same name that *isn't* meant as an overridden version of the original

This takes a little bit of language support, whereby the `__name` is mangled to include the name of the class - so that subclass versions of it get different names instead of overriding. It is still quite possible for a subclass or outside code to call that method if it really wants to - and the goal of name mangling is explicitly *not* to prevent that.

But because of all this, 'protected' turns out not to make much sense in Python - if you *really* have a method that could break invariants *unless called by a subclass* (and, realistically, you probably don't even if you think you do), the Python Way is just to document that. Put a note in your docstring to the effect of "This is assumed to only be called by subclasses", and run with the assumption that clients will do the right thing - because if they don't, it becomes their own problem.

Comment: 'Double underscores don't make a member 'private' in the C++ or Java sense...' - understood. That's why said 'private' in quotes. But thanks for the refresher.